# Class with Arduino, use SoftwareSerial as variable

Tags: class, arduino

Trying to use a class in Arduino 1.0 and setting SoftwareSerial as a variable with no success.

```
class SensorGPS: public Thread
{
  private: 
        SoftwareSerial* serialGPS; // RX, TX
  public:
        SensorGPS()
        {
          serialGPS = new SoftwareSerial(10,11);
          serialGPS.begin(4800);
        }
}
```

serialGPS.begin returns the error

```
arduino_sketch.ino: In constructor 'SensorGPS::SensorGPS()':
arduino_sketch:31: error: request for member 'begin' in '((SensorGPS*)this)->SensorGPS::serialGPS', which is of non-class type 'SoftwareSerial*'
arduino_sketch.ino: In member function 'virtual void SensorGPS::run()':
arduino_sketch:37: error: request for member 'read' in '((SensorGPS*)this)->SensorGPS::serialGPS', which is of non-class type 'SoftwareSerial*'
arduino_sketch:44: error: request for member 'write' in '((SensorGPS*)this)->SensorGPS::serialGPS', which is of non-class type 'SoftwareSerial*'
```

If remove * when setting the variable

```
SoftwareSerial serialGPS(10,11); // RX, TX
```

result error on the variable

```
arduino_sketch:21: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
arduino_sketch:21: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

This issue is on all kind of classes that needs values as initialisations. Another example with Dht11 module(1); generates same error.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the same issue with example Dht11 library. So I changed the constructor (library https://github.com/adalton/arduino/tree/master/projects/Dht11_Library).

Example Dht11 open the Dht11.h 
**From**

```
Dht11(uint8_t newPin) : humidity(-1), temperature(-1), pin(newPin) { }
```

**To (with added function setPin)**

```
Dht11() : humidity(-1), temperature(-1), pin(-1) { }

void setPin(uint8_t newPin) {
   pin = newPin;
}
```

So now in Arduino sketch I can set the pin before usage. This solution is possible to do for the majority of libraries.

```
class SensorTemperatureHumidity: public Thread
{
  private: 
        static const int Pin = 3;
        Dht11 module;
  public:
        SensorTemperatureHumidity() {
          module.setPin(Pin); // Set my pin usage
        }
}
```